# Find $\sin(y) $ in the following triangle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Find $\sin(y) $ in the following triangle.

Lenth $AB=2 \sqrt{3}$ and $AC=8$

> I find $\tan(x)= \frac {2}{\sqrt 3}$ and   $ \tan (2x +y  -\frac {\pi}{ 6}) =0$ and we can find $\tan(y)$

> Is there an another way for find $\sin(y)$  ? a simple way .

[image]

Comment: If only $AB$ and $AC$ is given, there is no way to compute $y$. From your computation it appears that more is given. For instance, what is $x$?

Comment: Normally, I would suggest using that $$\tan(r \pm s) = \frac{\tan(r) \pm \tan(s)}{1 \mp \tan(r)\tan(s)}$$ and the fact that $$(2x + y - \pi/6) = 0$$ to compute $\tan(y)$.  However, the question seems over-controlled and confusing.  I don't know what to do with the length of line segments $\overline{AB} = 2\sqrt{3}$ or $\overline{AC} = 8$.  Also, I am confused how you deduced that $\tan(x) = 2\sqrt{3}.$

Comment: @user2661923 $\displaystyle\frac{8}{\sin x}=\frac{2\sqrt 3}{\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{6})}$

Comment: Good, that resolves everything.  You have resolved both my confusion and my concern that the question is over-controlled.  You can use that $\tan(2x + y) = \tan(\pi/6)$, plus the formula in my first comment to determine $\tan(y)$ directly.

Comment: By the way, once $\tan(y)$ is determined, you then have that $\tan^2(y) + 1 = \frac{1}{\cos^2(y)}.$  This gives you $\cos^2(y)$ and therefore $\sin^2(y)$.

Comment: By the way, maybe solving for $\tan y$ is easier by

$$\tan y = \tan \left(\pi - 2x + \frac \pi 6\right) = -\tan\left(2x - \frac \pi 6\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is simpler than the method you followed (finding $\tan{y}$ and then $\sin{y}$) but this method gives you everything you need in one line and then the rest is simple algebra.

[image]

**Construction:** Produce the line $BA$ to $D$ such that $\angle ACD= 30°$. Thus $\angle BCD=x=\angle DBC$. Let $AD=m$, then $CD=BD= 2\sqrt 3+m$. Also, $\angle BDC=y-30°$ by exterior angle property.

**Using sine rule in $\Delta ACD$:**

$$\underset{(1)}{\frac{\sin{(\pi-y)}}{m+2 \sqrt 3}}=\underset{(2)}{\frac{\sin{30°}}{m}}=\underset{(3)}{\frac{\sin{(y-30°)}}{m}}$$

Notice that these three equations are sufficient to evaluate $\sin{y}$.

Using $(1)=(2)$,

$$\sin y= \frac{m+2\sqrt 3}{2m}=\frac1{2}+{\sqrt 3 \over m} \tag{i}$$

---

Using $(2)=(3),\; \;$ $m=\frac{4}{\sin{(y-30°)}} \; \implies \sin{y}= \frac1{2}+{\sqrt 3 \over 4}\sin{(y-30°)}$

You can solve the above trigonometric equation which will lead you to $$5 \sin y +\sqrt 3 \cos y=\frac1{2}$$ and then a quadratic equation $28 \sin^2 y-(26+14) \sin y+13=0$ solving which you'll get $\sin y=\frac{13}{14}$ after rejecting $\sin y=\frac{1}{2}$

But I'll suggest to calculate the value of $m$ using cosine rule in $\Delta ACD$ after (i) instead of making a trigonometric equation and then solving it.

---

In $\Delta ACD$

$$AD=m=\sqrt{8^2+(2\sqrt 3+m)^2- 2.8.(2\sqrt 3+m) \cos 30°}$$

$$ \require{cancel} \implies \cancel{m^2}=64+12+\cancel{m^2}+4\sqrt 3m-48-8\sqrt 3 m$$

$$\implies 4\sqrt 3m=64-36=28$$ $$ \implies m=\frac{7}{\sqrt 3}$$

Now, you just have to substitute the value of $m$ in $(i)$

$$\therefore \;\sin y= \frac{1}{2} +\frac{\sqrt 3. \sqrt 3}{7}=\frac{13}{14}$$

Comment: How you draw this shape ?  In Android?

Comment: Yes, in Android online using geogebra https://www.geogebra.org/geometry?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{8} = \frac{\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{6})}{2\sqrt3}$

$\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{8} = \frac{(\sqrt3 \sin x - \cos x)/2}{2\sqrt3}$

$\sqrt3 \sin x - 2 \cos x = 0 \implies \tan x = \frac{2}{\sqrt3}$

$\cos^2 x = \frac{1}{1 + \tan^2x} = \frac 37$

Also multiplying $\sqrt3 \sin x - 2 \cos x = 0$ by $\cos x ~ $, $~\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \sin2x  = 2\cos^2x$

Now $\sin y = \sin(2x - \frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac {\sqrt3}2\cdot \sin2x - \frac 12 \cdot\cos2x$

$= \cos^2x + \frac 12$

Answer (score 0):

As $\tan x=2/√3$, $x$ must be an acute angle. Hence, $\sin x=2/√7$ and $\cos x= √3/√7.$
We know that $2x+y-π/6=π,$
hence $2x+y=7π/6$. Taking $\sin()$ on both sides, $\ sin 2x.\cos y+\cos 2x.\sin y=-1/2$.
Now, $\sin 2x = 2\sin x.\cos x= 4√3/7$ and
$\cos 2x = (√2\cos x-1)(√2\cos x+1)= -1/7$.
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Building on my and @user2661923 comments

$2x+y=180+30$

$\tan(2x+y)=\tan30$

$\displaystyle\frac{\tan 2x+\tan y}{1-\tan 2x\tan y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$

$\displaystyle\frac{\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}+\tan y}{1-\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}\tan y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$

$\displaystyle\frac{\frac{\frac{4}{\sqrt3}}{1-\frac{4}{3}}+\tan y}{1-\frac{\frac{4}{\sqrt3}}{1-\frac{4}{3}}\tan y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$

Solve this and you will get $\tan y$ which will further give you $\sin y =\pm\frac{\tan y}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 y}}$

Comment: siny can only be positive.

Comment: @ilovemath Then you can drop the negative one

Comment: I wanted to say that you could have used a modulus function instead of a +/-  sign.